# Print statements are not printing to console, every time the function is called

Tags: python

When I input the right integers to call either hit() or miss(), the print statements are printed to console the first time, but do not print to console, after that. 
The players_turn() function gets called every time, but not the print statements.
I do not get any errors in my console either

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

board = []



for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(row))

def random_row(board):
  return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
  return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

def players_turn():
    for turn in range(4):
    print ("turn", turn +1)
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row: "))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col: "))

def hit():
    print ("direct hit")
    board[guess_col][guess_row] = "H"
    print_board(board)
    players_turn()

def miss():
    print ("you missed, try again")
    board[guess_col][guess_row]
    print_board(board)
    players_turn()

def out_of_range():
    print ("this is out of the range of the battle field")
    players_turn()

if_yes = str(raw_input("Do you want to play Battleship? "))

if if_yes == 'yes':
    print ship_row
    print ship_col
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row: "))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col: "))

if guess_col == ship_col and guess_row == ship_row:
    hit()
elif guess_col not in range(5) or guess_row not in range(5) :
    out_of_range()
else:
    miss()
```

I am expecting that every time I input the correct hit() credentials, I will get: 
"direct hit" and the board will be printed to console.
If the miss() credentials are met I will get:
"you missed, try again", and the board will be printed.

Comment: If `hit` is called, that first print must happen. Double check your data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Your posted code has three blocking points for me: (1) It fails to run as posted.  (2) Your code requires manual input; please provide an example that shows the error on its own.  (3) The code is not minimal; you've given us the entire program, rather than reducing it to the expected minimal case.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, you are correct. I will remove my comment, it was an error on my part misreading the line an exception was raised. It was raised at `print ship_row` which didn't work on my 3.X distribution

Comment: yeah sorry first time posting, and someone was able to make the edits before i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. I moved your code around without modifying much. I used Python 3.7. Here are the issues.

1. `raw_input` is discontinued. Use `input` instead.
2. Use `print` as a function in Python 3.x. So, you need parentheses. If you are using Python 2.x, you can ignore this.
3. After the user answers 'yes', they should go into the loop `players_turn`. So, the rest of the input requests and function calls go under it. Otherwise, it just asks for user input and does nothing
4. Now that you are looping through `players_turn` don't call it from other functions such as `hit`, `miss`, and `out_of_range`.
5. I also don't see the numpy being used anywhere.
6. The hit doesn't print to the right row and right column. I did not address that one. I only addressed the print issue.

Here is the updated code

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(row))

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

def hit():
    print ("direct hit")
    board[guess_col][guess_row] = "H"
    print_board(board)

def miss():
    print ("you missed, try again")
    board[guess_col][guess_row]
    print_board(board)

def out_of_range():
    print ("this is out of the range of the battle field")

def players_turn():
    for turn in range(4):
        print ("turn", turn +1)
        guess_row = int(input("Guess Row: "))
        guess_col = int(input("Guess Col: "))
        if guess_col == ship_col and guess_row == ship_row:
            hit()
        elif guess_col not in range(5) or guess_row not in range(5) :
            out_of_range()
        else:
            miss()

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

if_yes = str(input("Do you want to play Battleship? "))

if if_yes == 'yes':
    print (ship_row)
    print (ship_col)
    players_turn()
```

Comment: im very new to Python, hence the above issues that are apparent. Is there anyplace to learn better syntax and best practices?

Comment: python.org is an amazing resource. Good luck. If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.